Nuxt3 application hangs with Supabase module
I'm working on a new Nuxt3 project and I just installed the @nuxtjs/supabase and @nuxtjs/tailwindcss modules following the official documentation on their websites
npx nuxi@latest module add supabase
npx nuxi@latest module add tailwindcss

While TailwindCSS seems to be working fine, my development server hangs on a random page when I include @nuxtjs/supabase in the modules section of nuxt.config.ts
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  devtools: { enabled: true },
  modules: ["@nuxtjs/tailwindcss", "@nuxtjs/supabase"],
})

Removing @nuxtjs/supabase resolves the hanging issue, but I need to use Supabase in my application.
What I've Tried

Reinstalled all dependencies and supabase module
Verified installation guides for TailwindCSS and Supabase for Nuxt3
Cleared browser cache
Checked development server logs for any errors but couldn't find any in the console or browser's dev tools


Tried without using module add supabase?

Give a try to that one: https://github.com/nuxt-modules/supabase/issues/318#issuecomment-1854191570

As seen in this Github issue, this is a common issue that requires redirect to be set to false.

Redirect automatically to the configured login page if a non authenticated user is trying to access a guarded. You can disable all redirects by setting this option to false.

Probably because it infinite loops if there is no login page configured.
